# An apparent paradox: a different solution when transforming a linear equation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, arithmetic, infinity

If we have $y=a(y-x)+b$, and we set $a=1$, the solution of that equation will be $x=b$.

However, if we rewrite the equation as $y=\frac{a}{a-1}x-\frac{b}{a-1}$, and again we set $a=1$, we would get that both minuend and subtrahend would tend to infinity, since $\frac{a}{a-1} \rightarrow \infty$ and $\frac{b}{a-1} \rightarrow \infty$. We would therefore get something like $(\infty \cdot x - \infty)$.

Could you explain me how to solve or clarify this apparent paradox?

Answer (score 3):

Do not divide by zero.  In particular, do not set $a=1$ in $\frac{a}{a-1}$.

Comment: Thanks to everyone! I guess that the "undefined" adjective is referred to both $\frac{a}{0}$ and $(\infty \cdot x - \infty)$. Right? However, if I want to be practical, what should I do at this point? Should I just avoid to perform any transformation, and I then continue to use the first (original) linear equation, considering the case with $a=1$ as well? But, if I still want to use the transformed equation, should I just ignore the case with $a=1$?

Comment: Thanks a lot @GEdgar...but, a small doubt.... you wrote: "Only in the second case you can set $a=1$" ...Maybe you wanted to say "Only in the second case (i.e. $a\neq1$) you can set $a\neq1$", right?

Comment: Comment not worded well.  Better: The formal thing to do is to take two cass: $a=1$ and $a \ne 1$.  Only in the second case can you divide by $a-1$.

Comment: ..Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

When you rewrite the equation, you divide both sides by $a - 1$. This is not defined when $a = 1$, so you can only use the transformed equation when $a \neq 1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot Vladimir!

Answer (score 2):

Transforming a linear equation using division often creates undefined or missing solutions for specific values of x. For example, a=b$\implies$$\frac{a}{b}$=1, where if b=0, a=0 if a=b, but if we rephrase it to $\frac{a}{b}$=1, $\frac{a}{b}$ is undefined.

Comment: Thanks a lot Alexander!